# how i can setting <b-pagination-nav> bootstrap-vue component?

Tags: pagination, vue-component

I have this piece of code

```
[
  {
    "marque":"Aderma",
    "product":"A-DERMA SOINS ORIGINELS BAUME LEVRES 15ML",
    "price":"68",
    "marque":"Klorane",
    "product":"klorane SOINS ORIGINELS",
    "price":"28"
    ........
  }
]
```

How can I bind to it my array.

Answer (score 0):

As written the array only contains one item. The item is an object with duplicate fields.

I think you might be missing a `}` between `"price":"68"` and  `, "marque":"Klorane",`.